# How to avoid using Object.assign?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, observable

I am running a function to get a list of categories and for each category, get an id and run another function to get the number of 'links' in that particular category I have got the id.

For that, I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.categories = this.categoryService.getCategories();
        const example = this.categories.mergeMap((categor) => categor.map((myCateg) =>
            {
            this.categoryService.countCategoryLinks(myCateg.id)
                .map(numlinks => Object.assign(myCateg,{numLinks: numlinks}))
                .subscribe(valeur => console.log(valeur));
            return myCateg.id
        }));

       example.subscribe(val => console.log("valeur2: "+val));
    }
```

where getCategories() is:

```
getCategories(): Observable<any>
        {
         return this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}})

    };
```

and countCategoryLinks() is:

```
countCategoryLinks(id: number): Observable<any>
    {
    return this.category.countLinks(id)
    };
```

It appears, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

that numlinks is an Object. Of course this is done by Object.assign.

Is there a way to have the "count" inserted like **categoryName** ot clientId instead of an Object?

**My goal is to be able to show all the values in a template**:

```
<tr *ngFor="let category of categories | async; let id = index">
                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select"
                               for="row[3]">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="row[3]" class="mdl-checkbox__input"/>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><a [routerLink]="['/category/links']"></a>{{
                        category.categoryName }}
                    </td>
                     <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{category.numLinks}}</td>
                     <td #category.id><i (click)="deleteCategory(id)" class="material-icons">delete</i></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output in the way you want it?

Comment: What is "this.category.countLinks(id)" do?

Comment: I have added my template code.

Comment: this.category.countLinks(id) count the number of links for a particular id I am getting using getCategories(). The id is the Id field of Category as shown in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, then you can simply do this:

```
.map(numlinks => {
  myCateg.numLinks = numlinks.count;
  return myCateg;
})
```

Instead of

```
.map(numlinks => Object.assign(myCateg,{numLinks: numlinks}))
```

Therefore your code should become something like this:

```
{
  this.categories = this.categoryService.getCategories();

  const example = this.categories
    .mergeMap((categor) => categor
      .map((myCateg) => {

        this.categoryService
          .countCategoryLinks(myCateg.id)
          .map(numlinks => {
            myCateg.numLinks = numlinks.count;
            return myCateg;
          })
          .subscribe(valeur => console.log(valeur));

        return myCateg.id;
      }));

  example.subscribe(val => console.log("valeur2: " + val));
}
```

Comment: Shoud I write **.map(numlinks => myCateg.numlinks = numlinks.count)** ? This does not show anything in the console anymore.

Comment: this does not work : {
         this.categories = this.categoryService.getCategories();
        const example = this.categories.mergeMap((categor) => categor.map((myCateg) =>
            {
            this.categoryService.countCategoryLinks(myCateg.id)
                .map(numlinks => {
                    myCateg.numlinks = numlinks.count;
                   
            return myCateg.id
        });

                example.subscribe(val => console.log("valeur2: "+val));
                }))
    }

Comment: Just edited the source code with mine. It does not work.

Comment: I noticed that you are returning `myCateg.id` instead of `myCateg`

Comment: yes as I need to get the id to run the count(id). Just tried with myCateg only. Same issue. Is .subscribe(valeur => console.log(valeur)); supposed to write in the console? It shows nothing now. This is weird. Also, in my template, I show categories.CategoryName. So I think I should set categories variables at the end of all manipulations. What do you think?

Comment: You were missing some lines. Check my updated answer

Comment: Sorry yes I missed some lines ... So: It works as now numLinks is a property and not an Object anymore. **Thanks for that**. Problem: it is still not shown in my component Table.

Comment: Sadly I'm not versed in angular2, so I won't be able to help you in that regard.

Comment: I think this is because this.categories is not updated. It is not updated as it comes before transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
.map(numlinks => Object.assign(myCateg,{numLinks: numlinks}))
```

to:

```
.map(numlinks => Object.assign(myCateg, { numLinks: numlinks.count }))
```

Comment: "undefined" in the console and {{category.numLinks}} from the template is not shown.

Comment: @PhilippeCorrèges Updated the answer. Try again.

Comment: @PhilippeCorrèges, this seems to be the correct answer, no? That is the only issue you had: you assigned `numlinks` (an object with a count property), but want `numlinks.count` (the number alone).

Comment: as a part because it is not shown in my template with: {{category.numlinks}} while {{category.categoryName}} is shown.